# Count total numbers in the list

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I just want to ask on how to add a total number of users including when i filter it with eloquent the number also counts on how many is in the list. This is my code in EloquentUser. What code should i put that i can have like a variable that counts all the users even i filter it. I want a variable that is dynamic.

```
public function paginate($perPage, $search = null, $status = null, $emp_status = null, $level = null, $age = null, $gender = null, $civil_status = null, $role_id = null, $birthmonth = null, $company = null, $benefit = null)
    {

        $query = User::query();

        if ($status) {
            $query->where('status', $status);
        }

        if ($search) {
            $query->where(function ($q) use ($search) {
                $q->where('username', "like", "%{$search}%");
                $q->orWhere('email', 'like', "%{$search}%");
                $q->orWhere('first_name', 'like', "%{$search}%");
                $q->orWhere('last_name', 'like', "%{$search}%");
                $q->orWhere('middle_name','like', "%{$search}%");
            });
        }
        if (Auth::user()->hasRole('HR')) {
                    $query->where('role_id', '=', '3');
                };

        if($level && $level != "" && $level != "All" ) {
            $query->where(function ($q) use ($level) {
               $q->where('level', '=', $level);
            });
        }
        if($emp_status && $emp_status != "" && $emp_status != "All") {
            $query->where(function ($q) use ($emp_status) {
              $q->where('emp_status', '=', $emp_status); 
            });
        }
        if ($age && $age != "" && $age != 'All'){

            $range = explode('-', $age);

            if (count($range) > 1){
                $query->whereBetween('birthday', [now()->subYears($range[1]), now()->subYears($range[0])]);
            } 
            else{
                $query->where('birthday', '<', now()->subYears($range[0]));
            }
        }
        if($gender && $gender != "" && $gender != "All") {
            $query->where(function ($q) use ($gender) {
                $q->where('gender', '=', $gender);
            });
        }
        if($civil_status && $civil_status != "" && $civil_status != "All") {
            $query->where(function ($q) use ($civil_status) {
                $q->where('civil_status', '=', $civil_status);
            });
        }
        if($role_id && $role_id != "" && $role_id != "All"){
            $query->where(function ($q) use ($role_id) {
                $q->where('role_id', '=', $role_id);
            });
        }
        if($birthmonth && $birthmonth != "" && $birthmonth != "All"){
            $query->where(function ($q) use ($birthmonth) {
                $q-> whereMonth('birthday', '=', $birthmonth);
            });
        }
        if($company && $company != "" && $company != "All"){
        $query = User::whereHas('companies', function ($q) use($company) {
            $q->where('company_id','=', $company);
        });
        }
        if($benefit && $benefit != "" && $benefit != "All"){
        $query = User::whereHas('benefits', function ($q) use($benefit) {
            $q->where('benefit_id','=', $benefit);
        });
        }
        $result = $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->paginate($perPage);

        if ($search) {
            $result->appends(['search' => $search]);
        }  

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: long code, explain well

Comment: Sometimes I have the feeling that people is not asking for help but giving orders...

Comment: @Amarnasan I'm not giving orders I'm just asking

Comment: @MahdiYounesi i wanted to have a variable that counts the total number of  '$result'

Comment: You mean u want a separate key variable outside or inside the collection result?

Comment: Just a variable that will count the result @KennethSunday

Comment: u can always use the count() except for the paginate method cause there's a separate method in paginate to get the total_count, which is total().

Comment: I wanted the total because ill display it in my blade @KennethSunday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always use the `count()` method to all of your query method to get the current collection count except for paginate for some instance.

if we want to get the total count for paginated results.

you might want to consider the `total()` method when paginate() used.

Sample

```
$data['users'] = User::get();
$data['num'] = $data['users']->count();

return view("YOU_VIEW_HERE",$data);
```

You can use **$users** in your view and **$num** as well to display the necessary value.

Comment: Yes the paginated result I'm trying to get because I'll show it in the blade@Kennneth Sunday

Comment: for ->paginate(), you can simply use $results->total() considering that $results was pass via your controller to the view.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination

Comment: then in my blade ill just put $total?

Comment: for paginate() no need to save in $total variable anymore, just use the variable u have for the results. the call the method $results->total() to display the overall total of the search result.

Comment: Nice! :) dont forget to tag this concern as an answered so other dev will be informed just in case they have the same situation

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the paginated  $result variable  then you could go with

```
 $result->total
```

Comment: But when i display it in the blade it says undefined variable @Mahdi Younesi

Comment: dd() the $reault and give me the details

Comment: What's and where can i see it "dd()"?

Answer (score 0):

It already worked by using this code

```
$all = $users->total();
return view('user.list', compact('users', 'statuses','companies','benefits','all'));
```